# Creating Routes using react-router-dom from map method, but it's not redirecting to the JSX component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm still learning, just stuck on this ->
So basically I want to do this :-

```
<Switch>
      <Route path="/123" exact component={abcHandler} />
      <Route path="/456" exact component={abcHandler} />
      <Route path="/789" exact component={abcHandler} />
</Switch>
```

And the above code is working fine.
But I have other paths and components too, so I tried to use map method but for some reason it is not working.

```
const abc = ['123','456','789'];
<Switch>
          {abc.map(m=>{
            <Route path={`/${m}`} exact component={abcHandler} />
          })}
          </Switch>
```

First of all why this is not working and
Is there any way to perform the above task so that I can Redirect multiple paths to a single component without repeating same lines ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return from inside map block.

```
 const abc = ['123','456','789'];
    <Switch>
              {abc.map(m=>{
                return <Route path={`/${m}`} exact component={abcHandler} />
              })}
    </Switch>
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if you think it was solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `( )` instead of `{ }` on the `.map()` method where you map your array to return each generated JSX. `{ }` just executes the code inside it and does not return anything unless you specify with a `return something` statement.

```
const abc = ['123','456','789'];
<Switch>
      {abc.map(m => (
        <Route path={`/${m}`} exact component={abcHandler} />
      ) )}
</Switch>
```

When you try to achieve it with the code you have, all mapped elements return `undefined` since you have no return statement inside the block, but the normal parentheses provide context to the parser that all the value inside is going to be returned for the outer scope.

Notice that you could use `{ }` and achieve the same thing with a little addition, although it is unnecessary. Nonetheless, I will add it just to explain the concept better.

```
const abc = ['123','456','789'];
<Switch>
      {abc.map(m => {
        return (<Route path={`/${m}`} exact component={abcHandler} />)
      } )}
</Switch>
```